# biblatex: Full Citations in Footnotes on Every Page

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes, citing

How can I create this sort of bibliography using biblatex, ie, bibliography at the footer of every page?

[image: Example]

Comment: It seems to me that it can be obtained using `\footcite`s (or by setting `autocite` to `footcite`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is, basically, biblatex's [`verbose`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples) style, plus a few modifications (some of which I've included here; see the manual on how to do the rest):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt,DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
  \deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark})}
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode\quad(\@thefnmark)~\nobreak\relax#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]\footcite{companion}
\lipsum*[1]\footcite{moore}
\lipsum*[1]\footcite{iliad}
\lipsum*[1]\footcite{malinowski}
\lipsum*[1]\footcite{wilde}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: what you see in the footnotes is not a bibliography (strictly speaking). It's just the full bibliographic data of each work cited (hence the style's name) -- making a proper bibliography obsolete, or rather an optional favour you may do the reader: `\printbibliography`.

Comment: this solution works for scartcl but not with article. it stops on \deffootnotemark as Undefined control sequence. Is it possible to do this in article as well?