# bibtex cited in footnote

Tags: bibtex, citing, footnotes

I am writing books. The references are put in the footnote.
When I wrote papers I use Mendeley to generate the reference in a consistent way.
But how do I cite them into footnote?
Anyone has suggestion?

Comment: This seems to be answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139872/biblatex-full-citations-in-footnotes-on-every-page

Comment: Add notes in the note field of the bibtex ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Mendeley is a front-end for assembling information on bibliographic entrie, but it doesn't actually create the formatted bibliography. D you use BibTeX or biblatex to create the bibliography. If you use BibTeX, do you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `apacite`?  Please advise.

Comment: I had a difficulty: my \footcite in biblatex told me citation undefined.    I am using MikTeX and have compiled and run bibtex and recompile. But the bibtex generate error message saying no \citation found  etc. So, what should I do? Last time I made something and it came out....But don't know how did Imade that.

Comment: i use natbib instead of apacite